# Python - webbrowser.open() is opening my pdf file in Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: python, file, pdf, pythonpath, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to open a pdf file in my web browser using python. I made a simple test program when I was not able to open the pdf in the browser. This is the test code.

```
import webbrowser

web_url = 'https://www.google.com/'
file_url = r'file:///C:/Users......pdf' # full file path

webbrowser.get('windows-default').open(web_url)
webbrowser.get('windows-default').open(file_url)
```

This code opens the web_url in chrome but the file_url in Acrobat. However if I copy and paste the file_url string straight into the chrome search bar it displays the pdf. Anyone else encountered this.

FYI - I have tried the webbrowser.get('chrome'), webbrowser.get('google-chrome'), webbrowser.get('firefox'). All return the following error in console.

```
Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

I have also tried the other methods of opening such as webbrowser.open_new().

Also before trying to open in the browser I originally was opening in Adobe Acrobat Reader using the following.

```
os.startfile(full_file_path)
```

This was working and I am wondering if it may have cached something in memory which now means pdf files are opened in Adobe Acrobat Reader and not the browser?

Thanks

Comment: what's your default pdf viewer in the os?

Comment: Try "webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Adobe Acrobat is the default PDF viewer. When I change this to chrome the code will indeed open the PDF in chrome and not Adobe Acrobat. However, this isn't really the behaviour I desire. I would like it to open in chrome no matter what the default setting. The idea being that this code be deployed on many PCs.

Also I tried  open_new_tab(url) and it seems to behave exactly like open(url).